# Convert .png to "static const uint8_t" array

Tags: c, imagemagick

I need icons in the form *static const uint8_t* as I already have a *icons.h* library with many icons in this form. Typically each one about 70 lines long.

I have tried using the following ImageMagick command on a 64x64 [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) file:

```
convert /home/XXX/TempStuff/Arrow-circle-down.png -define h:format=gray -depth 8 -size 64x64 /home/XXX/TempStuff/grey64x64.h
```

But the result is a "static const unsigned char" array which is 87,000 lines long.

How can I convert a PNG file into a "static const uint8_t" array?

Comment: You probably mean `-resize` rather than `-size`.

Answer (score 1):

The `-size WxH` setting merely defines the size for any canvas you subsequently create, using `xc:red` or `gradient:cyan-yellow` or similar.

You actually, presumably, want to alter the size of an existing image, for which you need to use `-resize WxH` like this:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 64x64 result.jpg
```

---

If you want a header (a.k.a include) file, use `xxd` like this:

```
convert -size 8x8 xc:magenta a.rgb
xxd -i a.rgb
```

Output:

```c
unsigned char a_rgb[] = {
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff,
0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff ...
```

Hopefully you can see the RGB values of the first pixel are (255,0,255) which makes magenta (red + blue).

---

If you want just a greyscale image, prefix the output file with `gray:` like this:

```
convert -size 8x8 xc:magenta gray:a.dat
xxd -i a.dat
```

Comment: Ok, that resizes the image but the problem is in converting it into a "static const uint8_t" array. How do I do that?

Comment: I've updated it to cover *"header file"* creation.

Comment: @user2343618 an `unsigned char` is typically the same thing as a `uint8_t`.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I'm afraid that doesn't work. The result of using the commands you recommend result in a 64x64 png file of 1.3KB being converted into an 6.7MB array with a length of 6728446;

Comment: Mmmm, please share the exact image and exact commands you used by editing your question (not in comments) along with the first couple of lines of the header file.